# a grammatically wrong sentence in a book

Tags: grammar

The passage below is from Beefy's Cricket Tales By Ian Botham.

> Both Nasser and Duncan Fletcher were sticklers for good timekeeping,
>   so you made sure you were not late. On this particular occasion, I
>   wasn't late but as I approached the bus it started moving away. I ran
>   and caught up with it, banged on the door and got it to stop and let
>   me on. Nasser had been under pressure during the trip and **he often
>   used rows with people to let off steam**.

I think the bold faced part seems grammatically wrong and don't make any sense. 
It would be better the bold typed part to be “**he is often used to rows with people to let off steam**”.
Am I right or do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: No, I think _used_ here has the sense of _made use of_. The implication is that Nasser made pretexts to quarrel with people as a way of 'letting off steam'.

Comment: @KateBunting you might as well write an answer

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think you are right. *Used* here has the sense of *made use of*. The implication is that Nasser deliberately found pretexts to quarrel with people as a way of 'letting off steam'.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, "he often used rows with people" means that he is often used getting into loud or noisy arguments with people as a means of letting off steam, or releasing anger. The word "row" refers to a person having loud arguments or disputes with someone, as described in [Colin's Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/row). [british-english](/questions/tagged/british-english) [idioms](/questions/tagged/idioms) [expressions](/questions/tagged/expressions)

Comment: The word _is_ is not in the original version; the OP suggested adding it because they misunderstood the phrase _used to_, not the word _row_.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks. I edited my comment to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence

"*he often used rows with people to let off steam*"

is  grammatically correct.

***USE***  is a transitive verb  here
 and means
: [to take smth regularly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/use)

The sentence

"*he is often used to rows with people to let off steam*”

sounds strange.

According to [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/used%20to) :

"***used to***

adjective

: familiar with something so that it seems normal or usual

// I'm not used to driving this car yet."

Comment: Actually, I think here _use_ has the more common meaning of "to make use of (a device designed for the purpose) in accomplishing a task" [OED]. It is saying that he had rows (arguments) with people _for the purpose_ of letting off steam.

Comment: That's what I wanted to  say.